# Showing non-triviality of a function space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\varphi:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ be a function and $p\in [1,\infty)$. The function space $X$ defined by
$$
f\in X \longleftrightarrow \lim_{r\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{\varphi(r)}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|^p dy=0
$$
Show that under the assumption $\frac{\varphi(r)}{r^{\epsilon}}$ is increasing for some $\epsilon>0$ and $\inf_{r>\delta}\varphi(r)>0$ for all $\delta>0$ compactly supported bounded functions belongs to space $X$.

My attempt is: Let $f=\chi_{B(x,1)}$ then

$$
\frac{1}{\varphi(r)}\int_{B(x,r)}|\chi_{B(x,1)}(y)|^p dy=\frac{|B(x,r)\cap B(x,1)|}{\varphi(r)}=\frac{B(x,1)}{\varphi(r)}=\frac{1}{\varphi(r)}
$$
since we deal with big $r$. Then isn't it enough to $\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{1}{\varphi(r)}=0$ to prove the statement?

Comment: There seems to be something missing: Is the limit supposed to be finite ?

Comment: @daw Sorry for mistake. I edit the question.

Comment: Something missing about $\inf_{r>\delta}$. What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: @daw Oh sorry. I edit the question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correct reasoning for $\chi_{B(0,1)}$ and for the fact that all we need to assume is that $\lim_{r\to\infty}1/\varphi(r)\to 0$ (which follows from $\varphi(r)/r^\varepsilon$ increasing). However, the problem you stated appears to be that all compactly supported bounded functions belong to $X$, not just $\chi_{B(0,1)}$.

To do this, fix some such $f$ and note that the support, being compact, is bounded and thus has finite volume $V$. In addition, $\exists M\in\mathbb{R},|f|\leq M$ since $f$ is bounded. Thus, we have that
$$\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|^pdy\leq \int_{\mathrm{supp}(f)} K^p = VK^p$$
Thus, for any fixed $r$, we have
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R^n}}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|^pdy\leq  VK^p$$
and so, given only that $1/\varphi(r)\to 0$ as $r\to\infty$, we then obtain
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{1}{\varphi(r)}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R^n}}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|^pdy\leq  VK^p\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{1}{\varphi(r)} = 0$$

Comment: I can not understand. Why we need two assumptions which stated in question? In your answer you also don't use these assumptions.

Comment: @user315531 I’m agreeing with you in this answer. You don’t need the two assumptions. Instead all you need is what you suggested: that $1//varphi(r)$ tends to 0.